# Programming ATMega328 (using Arduino) to program other ATMega328s?

Tags: arduino, integration, bootloader, atmega

I've started working with IC chips and I've found some ATMega328 chips that I bought a while ago, I was then considering buying a very cheap Arduino and bootloading the chips with the Arduino IDE and operating software.

My main question being is it possible for me to program one chip with an ATMega328 with an Arduino as an ATMega328 programmer to bootload and program further IC chips?

Also I was thinking, as the ATTiny85 chip is very similar to the ATMega328, could I essentially use the same system (maybe using one of those IC tester board sockets) to program this chip and any others (if so, please specify if possible)?

Thanks in advance for all answers,
Rish.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://hackaday.com/2012/02/21/flash-an-arduino-from-an-sd-card/

Answer (score 1):

There are many [tutorials](http://www.instructables.com/id/Burning-the-Bootloader-on-ATMega328-using-Arduino-/) on how to do this.

Comment: This doesn't show how to later on use the programmed ATMega chip as a bootloader/programmer bridge to software.

Comment: @Rishi - your comment doesn't make sense. Have you used the Arduino platform before? You will still need some additional components in order to actually use the chip once you have burned the bootloader on it - there is SO much info on all of this - help yourself a bit, hey. http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/JamecoBuilds/arduinocircuit.html and http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-Your-Own-Arduino/

Comment: rishi once you've set up the atmega with a bootloader, you need to make it work electronically before using it. @TOMATO gave you everything you need to get started. And btw, TOMATO, you should add "Yes, this is possible" to start your answer.. by answering the OP's question :-)